# How to get the NaN value in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to get a `NaN` value directly in BigQuery? For example, I'm trying to get all the 'special' float values BQ supports, but what's the way to generate the `NaN`?:

```
SELECT   1e500,    -1e500,    1e-500,  -1e-500,   ???
   --    Infinity  -Infinity  0.0      0.0        NaN
```

Is the only way to do `CAST('NaN' AS float64)` ? Or is there a way to represent it with scientific notation?

Answer (score 2):

Another options (few out of many similar - you got an idea)

```
SELECT IEEE_DIVIDE(0, 0), LOG(1, 1e500)
```

with output

[image]

Comment: also,  `COS(1e500)` and so on ...